# pyodbc MS Access

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access

Я пытаюсь вставить данные в таблицу товары но не получается

```
cur.execute(f"""
            INSERT INTO Товары ("Название") VALUES ({"g"})
                    """)
```

Пишет слишком мало параметров. Требуется 1.
Сколько я не смотрел и не менял ОНО ПРОСТО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ.
Я видел что она у многих не работает просто потому что они пишут в одно строчку а не через табы. Библиотека pyodbc кривая?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Приведите [mcve] и полный текст ошибки без отсебятины

Comment: Ну и в целом непонятно, почему вы решили, что запросы вообще можно писать так, как написали вы. Посмотрите примеры в документации хотя бы что ли https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor

Comment: Я писал запросы по разному и с кавычками и без и много как еще. Смотрел я доки.
Но проблема решилась... просто надо привязать переменную к тексту запроса и передать эту переменную в cur.execute(). Но почему так, я не понимаю.
Доки я читал, но все равно не смог решить эту проблему пока просто не записал в переменную сам запрос. Поэтому прошу просто указать на ошибку и объяснить почему это не работает так как должно. Я буду очень признателен т.к я просто не могу понять почему переменная все исправила, и сколько бы я ни рылся в инете не смог понять где здесь ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Вот минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
import pyodbc as db

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\store.accdb;'
    )

conn = db.connect(conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(f"""

    INSERT INTO Товары (Название) VALUES ('{"g"}')

    """)

cur.commit()
```

Вот этот код работает. Нужно было просто кавычки по другому поставить.